# Azure powershell - accessing compute emulator

Tags: azure-powershell

Can you point me to how I can use Get-AzureRole cmdlet on the Compute Emulator? I am trying to find the various values that needs to be passed while calling Set-AzureSubscription and Select-AzureSeubscription (for compute emulator) which seems to be a pre-requisite for Get-AzureRole

Answer (score 0):

You can run a startup task cmd/powershell and install the cmdlet snap-in shown here:
http://blog.smarx.com/posts/windows-azure-startup-tasks-tips-tricks-and-gotchas

That will install the Cmdlets snap-in and execute your powershell script(s).

Not sure what you are trying to do though, you do have the OnStart() method you can override and add code in programatically inside a web/worker role.  Would be a lot easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Get-AzureRole is maeant to be used agaisnt live azure.  Access to the compute emulator is through the start-azureemulator command or the csrun command line tool.

What information would you actually like to get about the role?